# Read int from char array

Tags: arrays, c, sockets, unix, byte

I'm programming in C.

Suppose that I receive a datagram with Berkely socket UDP.
I receive 20 bytes.
So I have a char buffer[20] where I can memorize this data.

Now I want to use the first 4 bytes as an int and the other as a char.

```
int varnumber;
memset(buffer,0x0, 20);
recvfrom(sd, buffer, 20, 0, (struct sockaddr *)Addr, &Len);
```

So if I want put into "varnumber" I have written this code:

```
varnumber=*((int *)&(buffer[0]));
```

This way is correct? If it isn't how can I do this? I can't change the packet received from the socket.

---

P.S.

I send from a server this datagram in order.
Every datagram has a counter in this 4 bytes.
So for example, I have:

**datagram1:**
00000000 00000000 00000000 000000001 ...(other char)...

**datagram2:**
00000000 00000000 00000000 000000010 ...(other char)...

ecc...

I tried to printf `varnumber` for a lot of datagrams received. I read the numbers all in perfect order, but from 93 onwards I read jumps straight to number 1001.

I tried to see these packets on Wireshark and Wireshark doesn't show any problem, in fact If I visualize the counter in the datagram in the time order I see the correct order. My c program doesn't read 93 but read 1001. I don't know why.

I know that UDP does not guarantee the order, but I'm in localhost and this is so strange. It is also a problem that I always see, it is not occasional.

Comment: You need to make sure you get the octets in the proper byte order for your CPU. Shifting and adding each octet is a better approach.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Maybe [this question and its discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978340/how-to-read-4-bytes-of-data-from-a-given-char-pointer-in-c) can help you.

Comment: I have the same problem with memcpy. So I'm thinking that the problem isn't the byte order but It's a problem with UDP. Why I visualize all ok on Wireshark and with my client not?

Comment: I'd suggest you print the raw data from `recvfrom()` byte-by-byte in hex, and compare that with what you see in Wireshark. If I were in your position, I'd want to check whether the problem was in the data I was receiving, or the way my program was interpreting it. I'd echo the view of @DavidRTribble that you would do better to assemble the bytes into an integer using arithmetic, rather than doing a cast that will only work on some CPU architectures.

Comment: Wireshark visualizes packet with correct values. Shouldn't this be enough to say that there are no problems with the transfer?

Comment: Any idea to solve my problem?

Comment: Can you share another structure between sending and receiving software? send/receive directly from/to a struct?  an `int` could be placed at a naturally aligned offset within a struct and store/load the `int` with `htonl()` and `ntohl()`

Comment: suggest inserting a `sleep( 1 )` in the server transmit loop to see if the rate of incoming packets is overrunning the ability of the client to process those packets

Comment: suggest removing: `memset(buffer,0x0, 20);`  because the call to `recvfrom()` will completely overlay that buffer.

Comment: regarding: `recvfrom(sd, buffer, 20, 0, (struct sockaddr *)Addr, &Len);` strongly suggest checking the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.